# Multiple Java service refer same data contracts. WCF client generate duplicate data contracts for shared data contracts

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-client

The WCF client is generating duplicate data contracts under different namespace for shared data contracts used in  multiple Java services.

Example: 2 Java Service using shared.xsd this schema has approx 1000 complex and simple types defined.

1. Booking Service uses two schemas 

 **a. Booking.xsd** 
**b. shared.xsd**

2. Ticketing Service uses two schemas 
**a. Ticketing.xsd** 
**b. shared.xsd**

When i add a service reference in Visual Studio for both the services the data contracts define in Shared.xsd are created under namespaces provided.

So for example Person class is defined twice, one in Foo.BookingService namespace and similarly in Foo.TicketingService namespace.

Is there a way, i can specify a command option or through visual studio that it should reuse the Shared.xsd data contracts and should not regenerate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use svcutil.exe to generate .NET datacontract types that conform to XML serializer format.  e.g.

svcutil.exe /target:code /dataContractOnly /serializer:XmlSerializer /importXmlTypes  [your xsd file's path]

Comment: Thanks Hari, after extracting the data contract. How do i then generate the proxy client without the previously extracted dataContract. after executing above code, should i execute svcutil booking.wsdl.... this throws error if i dont specify the xsd. Appreciate you response on this